# Windows licensing for companies

Tags: windows, license

Let's assume that a company has 10 workers.

Does the company have to buy a license for each computer or is there another way in which Microsoft sells licenses to companies?

Answer (score 2):

[Open Value](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/open-license.aspx#tab=1) option seems suitable for you (offered for organizations with >5 and <250 PCs). [This page](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/open-license.aspx#tab=2) gives a detailed table about the benefits.

Comment: Open Value is probably the right option here. In answer to the part of the question "does the company have to buy a license for each computer" the short answer is yes - there is no "carte blanche" option that will allow you to buy a single licence to cover a whole site, or company. No matter what programme you go for, ultimately the number of licences you buy relates to the number of machines (or user) you have.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offer many types of licensing depending on how many licenses you require.

There is a great deal of information available on the [Volume Licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/) page

Answer (score 0):

As far as I now Microsoft does NOT offer Windows licenses in Volume License - offers ONLY Windows UPGRADE ! So, if you want to buy 10 Windows license for 10 computers, you have to buy 10 OEM/FPP Windows license, then you can buy 10 upgrade license in VL (Volume License).

Why is it so? Because Microsoft has OEM partners and wants you to buy PCs with OEM Windows. Then you can upgrade to newer version:

a) buying upgrades in VL

b) buying new PCs with new OEM Windows.

---

If 10 users use 10 computers then you need 10 license. If these users work in shifts and you have only e.g. 5 computers then you need 5 licenses.